# Return id from collection insert

Tags: meteor

I want to run an update query on a mongo db collection and to do that I need the id of the user that I store in the database. This is my insertion code:

```
if(userAccounts.find().count()==0){
  userAccounts.insert({
    username:Meteor.user().username,
    likedPosts: [{
  postId: [this._id],
  createdAt: new Date()
}]
  });
```

To run the update query I need the id from the userAccounts database. So I need something like:

```
var id=userAccounts(query); // And this should return me the id
```

Comment: From the same collection? Are you asking how to return only the `_id` value? And by what query? For the `"username"`?

Comment: I need only the _id value. Idk what query, that's why I am asking I just want smth that returns me only the _id from the userAccounts collection.

Comment: Like `.findOne().fetch()._id` ?

Comment: You saved my life ! @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0):

`.insert()` returns the `_id` of the inserted document (if successful).

```
const _id = userAccounts.insert({
  username: Meteor.user().username,
  likedPosts: [{
    postId: [this._id],
    createdAt: new Date()
  }]
});
```